# IE source code placeholder control for my VBA scraper

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I have the following code which opens an IE page, and fills in the fields with the value "caravan". However I only need the first field to be filled in with "caravan". I need the second one to be filled in with "2016" for example. I've had trouble with this task because I can't seem to uniquely identify each element within the input tag (to which all of the fields belong).

Here is my code:

```
Sub Quote()



Dim ie As Object

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.navigate ("https://insurance.qbe.com.au/portal/caravan/form/estimate")

ie.Visible = True

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readystate = 4



Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readystate = 4


Set inputCollection = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")



For Each inputElement In inputCollection


inputElement.Value = "Caravan"


Next inputElement


Loop


End Sub
```

So it's taking each "inputElement" that is housed within the "input" tag, and where possible, it's making a corresponding field's display value be that of "caravan".

To illustrate why I'm having difficulty in uniquely identifying each field, here is the source of the first two fields (first one is for caravan type; second one is for caravan year-of-manufacture):

First one

[image]

Second one

[image]

So neither have an id. And both are within the "input" tag and both have the same classname. So I can't get-element-by-id or get-elements-by-classname. I've tried getting elements by classname in a wide range of ways and it simply does nothing (no error is produced and the web page isn't affected).

The only way I've managed to fill in a field is through using the code I have above. But, again, it's changing **all** the fields of course. I figure that the only thing I can really use to get my code to tell the two apart is the placeholder element of each one.

But how do I achieve this seeing as you cannot "get element by placeholder"

//

I've since tried to confirm that there's no way to use classname, with the following code modification:

```
Set inputCollection = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

For Each inputElement In inputCollection

If ie.document.getElementsByClassName.Value = "ui-select-search ui-select-toggle ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" Then inputElement.Value = "Caravan"
```

Comment: I've been searching online but just can't find anything like what I need - any suggestions on what to search for? I've looked for the outrageous like "get element by placeholder vba" to "control webtags using vba" to "vba to control source code which has no id" to "vba when classnames and tags are identical" - I'm at a loss on this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my! How exciting!! I finally found out how to do this after literally days of searching online. It always had to be something simple (but, alas, this isn't my area of expertise at all so it's always going to be really challenging for me). Anyway, this code works (and I expect I will need to put a fire-event line in soon):

```
Set inputCollection = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("input")



For Each inputElement In inputCollection

If inputElement.getAttribute("placeholder") = "Caravan type" Then

inputElement.Value = "Caravan"

Exit For

End If

Next inputElement
```

I was so unaware of "getAttribute" but it makes so much sense. If you don't have an id and some of the fields you are looking at have the same classname (as can often be the case), then you need to rely on other unique attributes and use this sort of code.

If you're wondering where I found out about this, I found this pretty cool Youtube channel, and here's the specific video that helped me:

https://www.youtube.com/user/alexcantu3/videos

Hope it helps someone else some day!